# VBA - Replace doesn't work in some cells

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I work with some data extracted from a database. In a column, I have a set of data in the format dd.mm.yyyy. I'm using the lines below to try to convert these values to dd/mm/yyyy and format as date.

```
.Range(Columns(j), Columns(j)).Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/"
.Range(Columns(j), Columns(j)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

After executing the code, all the replaces were done, and the cells are formated as date, but some values are left aligned, and some are right aligned. When I active the filter in this column, some values are not correct grouped per year (screenshot below).

[image: Column with filter activated]

When I go to a value that seems not to be working (for example, the first 13/01/2015 of the screenshot), it is left aligned. Then, if I double click in the cell and press enter, the cell become right aligned.

I have searched for extra characteres in these cells (blank spaces, for example), but did not find anything.

Do you have any ideas about this problem?

*p.s.: sorry for my bad english, I am from Brazil (:*

Comment: What is your default date format?  If it's m/d/yyyy then Excel will try to interpret 13/01/2015 using the default format and that will fail (since month is >12), so the value will not be recognized as a date.

Comment: It's dd/mm/yyyy. Portuguese is my default language. But you are correct about the problem: Excel is considering the values as mm/dd/yyyy, and trying to convert to dd/mm/yyyy. But I don't know why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text to columns can be used to convert dates from one format to another. Manually, you'd select the range, click Text to Columns > Next > Next > select "Date" and specify the order of day, month, year that the **SOURCE** data is in, then click OK.

Of course, the same can be done with VBA. Fire up the macro recorder, follow the steps above and study the resulting code.

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
    :="", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly! (:

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you have dates formatted as text. I have a trick that I use to kill those formatting issues:

1. Select whole column
2. Go to Tab `DATA`
3. Click on `TEXT TO COLUMN`
4. Pick `Delimited` and click Next
5. Uncheck all boxes and click Finish
6. Select whole column
7. Format it as Short Date